# How to convert columns from CSV file to json such that key and value pair are from different columns of the CSV using python?

Tags: python, json, csv, raspberry-pi3

I have a CSV file with which contains labels and their translation in different languages:

```
name                      en_GB     de_DE
-----------------------------------------------
ElementsButtonAbort       Abort     Abbrechen
ElementsButtonConfirm     Confirm   BestÃ¤tigen
ElementsButtonDelete      Delete    LÃ¶schen
ElementsButtonEdit        Edit      Ãndern
```

I want to convert this CSV into JSON into following pattern using Python:

```
{
    "de_De": {
        "translations":{
            "ElementsButtonAbort": "Abbrechen"
                       }
             },
   "en_GB":{
       "translations":{
           "ElementsButtonAbort": "Abort"
                      }
             }
 }
```

How can I do this using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your data is as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["ElementsButtonAbort", "Abort", "Arbrechen"],
                   ["ElementsButtonConfirm", "Confirm", "BestÃ¤tigen"],
                   ["ElementsButtonDelete", "Delete", "LÃ¶schen"],
                   ["ElementsButtonEdit", "Edit", "Ãndern"]],
                   columns=["name", "en_GB", "de_DE"])
```

Then, this might not be the best way to do it but at least it works:

```
df.set_index("name", drop=True, inplace=True)
translations = df.to_dict()
```

Now, if you want to have get exactly the dictionary that you show as desired output, you can do:

```
for language in translations.keys():
    _ = translations[language]
    translations[language] = {}
    translations[language]["translations"] = _
```

Finally, if you wish to save your dictionary into JSON:

```
import json

with open('PATH/TO/YOUR/DIRECTORY/translations.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(translations, fp)
```

Comment: thanks that worked. can you please also tell me how to import the data in pandas Dataframe from csv directly rather then hard coding it? since it is a very long file  of translations and it gets modified quite often so it would be easier to import values into the dataframe.

Comment: Sure! So what you would usually do is: ```df = pd.read_csv("path/to/your/file.csv", sep=",")```. Please note that sometimes, the separator used in the csv is not a comma, but can be things like ```sep = "\t"```, ```sep=" "```, etc...